# Serialize huge array to XML on Heroku?

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, serialization

I have an app created under Symfony and Heroku.
There is a worker dyno (with 512M memory_limit) which is here to get all data from a database table and serialize them to XML (for now, it's approximatively 3000 rows).

When I try to serialize, the serialization stops always at the same moment so I have half an XML file of 600Kb instead of one of 21Mb normally, and no ending tags.
I have no error log and the process finish well, because I send an email at the end of it and I receive it every time.

Do you have any idea ? I've looked for the memory limit but it seems to be something else.

Comment: I think you are hitting some memory limit or a software exception or error which is catched and doesn't print anything.  Can you monitor the memory limit while generating the file? Are you fetching all the data in memory and generate that xml file, or are you using line-by-line fetching and write it object by object? 
I know that generating huge files with thousands of database records could end up taking all your memory

Comment: I will try to monitor, do you know how to do it ?
I am fetching all rows then loop on it to create an array of the data, formatted as I need. First time I do it, so not sure what's the best solution

Comment: It depends on which library you use. Since you are using symfony I think you are also using doctrine.  You can find more information here https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing

Comment: I don't think it's related to Doctrine, I successfully create my array of modified data (based on my entities), the error seems to be related to the serializer not being able to deal with this array of 3000+ data (but only on Heroku, because it works well on my local env with 128M memory_limit)

Comment: Process was too huge for Heroku (and others I guess) so I decided to split this : I serialize entities one by one instead of the entire array of entities. Now it works well. Thanks for your help !